# how can i get dynamic url in nodejs? (mernstack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

hi im trying to make forgot password/reset password service.

let me show you the logic of this service.

(simply, send email in react(localhost:3000/forgotPassword) -> click link in email -> route to localhost:3000/resetPassword)

**1.send email in frontend**
[image]

The content is to write down the email of the account you joined.

**2.email**
[image]

비밀번호 리셋하기 <- this is direct to http://localhost:3000/resetPassword

[image]

3.forgotPassword.js in node.js

[image]

Here, I want to change resetURL(http://localhost:3000/resetPassword) to dynamic URL. Because I will distribute this soon.

**3.package.json in react**
[image]

I was able to do api communication from react to node by specifying proxy here, but /api/resetPassword does not work in node.

To sum up, I want to use the code used by React on the node as well. Like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to environmentalise your configuration.

You could do it through an environment variable, like this:

```
const baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
const resetURL =`${baseURL}/resetPassword`
```

If you use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package, you can support configuration through environment variables or from a `.env` file.

Comment: This setting does not allow you to go to localhost:3000 when distributed later.

Comment: If you do not set any configuration in the environment, it will use localhost:3000. When you deploy to production, you set the production base URL in the environment.

Comment: When I distributed, the localhost:5000/forgotPassword did not work in the react.
But after setting proxy, /api/forgotPassword worked.
Isn't it the same with Nodejs?
After distribution, can the localhost:3000/forgotPassword work?

Comment: How are the routes assembled in your server? It sounds like your dev environment is using some kind of hot-reload server?

Comment: https://github.com/k3kys/shop3,  backend/controller/authController, backend/routes/userRoutes

Comment: Your route is not defined as 'api/resetPassword': https://github.com/k3kys/shop3/blob/master/backend/routes/userRoutes.js#L11

Comment: ok you're right, my misunderstaning. have a nice day sir

Comment: this is so helpful ^^

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your interested in setting up a dynamic variable for the url in your react app. Try just setting an environment config file, either a file for each environment you are developing in (i.e., Dev, QA, PROD) or a single file with multiple shared Env variables. You can even add an env variable to your package.json file for example.

**NOTE** the approach below would work for linux and mac, but not windows
please use the resources below for more information. This approach has been made available for react-scripts@0.9.0 and higher.

```
{
 "scripts": "APP_URL=http://localhost:300 npm start"
}
```

Resources:

- https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5
- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/